# How can I identify tags that do not have CSS selectors with Html.Table?

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, powerbi-desktop, m

I am writing a query for work for a report that has some poorly written HTML code where only some of the  tags have a CSS selector I can use for creating my columns but others don't. (Guess who wrote it?) I wrote some workarounds using nth-child and describing each step to the desired tab but, as expected, when scaled up to all the other reports it causes issues because not every table is alike with what it contains.

My working code:

```
        {"Rule ID", "td[class='rule-id']"}
```

However the next column I used this:

```
        {"Time", "div[class='panel-body'] > TABLE > TBODY > TR:nth-child(6) > TD:nth-child(2)"}
```

Which in some of the tables does grab the time, but in others it grabs the wrong tag. I'm wondering if there's a way I can refer to the information in-between the  tags. The time code looks like this:

```
<table>
  ...
  <tr>
    <td>Time</td>
    <td>2022-04-28T10:01:15+00:00</td>
  </tr>
  ...
</table>
```

I tried this but it results in a 100% empty column:

```
 {"Time", "td[contains='Time']"}
```

This is my first project in Power BI so I'm learning as I go and have found answers to most of my questions through Google but I couldn't quite phrase this question properly to find a good result. All of the code is on my GFE so I can't get it over here to share, hopefully the bits I could share are enough.
Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

If you link the site I can give a better answer.

---

There's an optional 3rd parameter, that gives you more access to attributes.

`{"Name", "Selector"}` would become `{"Name", "Selector", each _ }`, ex:

```
= Html.Table(Source,
        {
            {"Name", "Selector", each _ }
        }
    )
```

### selector

> td[contains='Time']

This isn't looking for what your html, it would match this. Here's a good reference/cheatsheet

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors

```
<td contains='Time'>
```

### Testing Selectors in a browser

In the web console, you can use a CSS Selector query to preview what it will select.

Firefox has shorthand using the function `$` and `$$` . otherwise use `document.querySelector()` and `document.querySelectorAll()`

#### Your `RowSelector`

If you were to use `$$("TABLE.table > * > TR")` as your `RowSelector`

[image: horizontal-preview]

#### Your `columnNameSelectorPairs`

And then `TABLE.table > * > TR > :nth-child(1)`

[image: vertical-preview]

From:

- [ninmonkeys.com/Select_Tables_using_your_own_CSS_Selectors](https://ninmonkeys.com/blog/2021/01/31/power-query-custom-functions-cheat-sheet/#Select_Tables_using_your_own_CSS_Selectors)
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors

Comment: Thank you for the answer, there isn't an actual site because the reports are actually XCCDF files with an HTML version. I had a set up similar to your last suggestion where I 'mapped' to the desired tag and used nth-child to do so as well, but this failed when scaled up because some of the tables did not have the same amount of rows. So if there are no CSS attributes in the tag then I can't accurately reference it with the information in-between the text? It seems as though I will have to bring all the data in and parse it into columns some other way. Thanks for the help!